# Mongoose update/upsert?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've looked at some of the questions on the site and haven't quite figured out what I'm doing wrong. I've some code like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/lastfm'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
User = new Schema({
  nick: String,
  hmask: String,
  lastfm: String
});
var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);

//Register user to mongodb
var reg_handler = function (act) {
// should add a new entry to the db if nick (act.nick) && hmask (act.host)
// aren't already in the db. Otherwise, update the entry that matches nick
// or hostmask with the new lastfm name (act.params)
};

var get_handler = function (act) {
  UserModel.find({ nick: act.params }, function (err, users) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) };
    users.forEach(function (user) {
      console.log('url for user is http://url/' + user.lastfm);
    });
  });
};
```

I'm not sure what I should be doing in the middle there to get it to update the database properly. I've tried quite a few things, can't undo to find out all what I've tried though. It's taken a large portion of my night and I want it working.

This is almost what I want, I wonder if there is any way to do an OR in the conditions part of the `.update()`

```
var reg_handler = function (act) {
  var lfmuser = { nick: act.nick, hmask: act.host, lastfm: act.params };
  UserModel.update({ nick: act.nick }, { $set: lfmuser }, { upsert: true }, function(){});
};
```

I will keep toying around with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var reg_handler = function (act) {
  UserModel.update({ $or: [{nick: act.nick}, {hmask: act.host}] }, { $set: { lastfm: act.params } }, { upsert: true }, function(){});
};
```

This does exactly what I wanted, and it's one line. :D Perfect!

Comment: You might want to add some error handling to that last function ;)

Answer (score 9):

Use [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) with the 'upsert' option set to true.

Comment: Is there any reason why this is better (or worse) than `Model.update()` in the accepted answer?

Comment: @joeytwiddle what I would suggest is if you want to only update and not get back the record, then do Model update, otherwise, findOneAndUpdate will work if you want the record back.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (haven't test, but *should* work with latest mongoose):

```
UserModel.findAndModify({nick: act.nick, hmask: act.host}, [], {$set: {lastfm: act.params}}, {}, callback);
```

Comment: Will test it, did get it to work with .update() finally. I don't know what I was doing wrong before, but it works fine now.

Comment: Nope, this crashes it. Will answer with what I finally got to work.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to define schema for particular collection

**user schema:**

`username: {type: String, required: true,  upsert: true }`

**use in code:**

```
.findOne({ emailId: toEmail })
.update({$set: { username: ravi }})
.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate()` and need to set `{new: true}`.
You can check the [4.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes#backwards-breaking-changes), according to which "new" is by default
`false`.

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { nick: act.nick },       //your condition for check
  { $set: lfmuser },       //new values you want to set
  { upsert: true, 'new': true }).exec(function (err, data){
      //your result    
  });
);
```